# The android studio "run" button does not appear

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

My android studio stopped showing the "run" button (before it showed this project without problems). I've tried several solutions like: "invalidate caches", "sync project with gradle files" and "try run using shortcut shift + F10", but none of it worked.

The selected module is correct.

[image: android studio button run not showing]

### My Android Studio Version

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.wakatime.intellij.plugin (13.1.14), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.20-release-275-AS7442.40), com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.4), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

Comment: What version of AS do you have ?

Comment: Hi @Areyana I updated the question description with the Android Studio Version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem as follows:

1. Click "build" on the top bar of Android Studio;

[image]

2. In the menu that opens, access the "clean project" option;

[image]

3. Go to the "build" option again;

[image]

4. In the menu that opens, access the option "rebuild project".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As IntelliJ products are very highly customizable, it is possible that you deleted the `Run` button.

Go to
`Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > Menus and Toolbars`

Search for `Toolbar Run Actions / Run/Debug`
If you do not see `Run`, you may restore by `Restore Actions`

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Dolphin
Go to TabBar -> File -> Repair IDE.
Look warning and click repair index.This was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio, delete .idea folder, restart AS.